# Unity3D - Order list by angle to point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, convex-hull, rigid-bodies

I am trying to make a 2D game in unity. I want to create a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) around a group of rigidbody2Ds that I have in a List. To do this, I need to order the List by the angle that each rigidbody2D makes with the start position. Anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to sort a list by a computed value.

```
        return list.OrderBy(c =>
        {
            return /*ANGLE COMPUTATION*/;
        }).ToList();
```

and that angle computation could be the dot product between the (normalized) vectors.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

There are readily available implementations for convex hulls algorithms though, such as this one: https://github.com/masphei/ConvexHull

Comment: Thanks! I thought LINQ was the answer, but couldn't quite get my head around it.